# Conditionally finish promise in chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ecmascript-6, bluebird

I have a Promise chain where I perform a number of actions. When I reach a certain `then` statement, I want to create a fork where it might continue the chain, but otherwise, will resolve the entire upcoming chain of promises.

```
readFile('example.json').then(function (file) {
    const entries = EJSON.parse(file);
    return Promise.each(entries, function (entry) {
      return Entries.insertSync(entry);
    });
  }).then(function () {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      return readFile('fakeUsers.json');
    } else {
      // I am done now. Finish this chain.
    }
  })
  // conditionally skip these.
  .then(() => /** ... */)
  .then(() => /** ... */)
  // finally and catch should still be able to fire
  .finally(console.log.bind('Done!'))
  .catch(console.log.bind('Error.'));
```

Is this possible to do with promises?

Comment: Your code says `insertSync`, should that be `insertAsync`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attach the conditional `then` handlers to the returned promise in the condition itself, like this

```
readFile('example.json').then(function (file) {
    return Promise.each(EJSON.parse(file), function (entry) {
      return Entries.insertSync(entry);
    });
  }).then(function () {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
      return readFile('fakeUsers.json')
        .then(() => /** ... */ )
        .then(() => /** ... */ );
    }
  })
  .finally(console.log.bind('Done!'))
  .catch(console.log.bind('Error.'));
```

If you are using Node.js v4.0.0+, then you can use arrow functions like this

```
  .finally(() => console.log('Done!'))
  .catch(() => console.log('Error.'));
```